# ¿Como obtener el valor del ultimo elemento de una tabla dinamica, jquery?

Tags: jquery

De esta forma genero la tabla dinámicamente:

```
var cupones_bienvenida_todos = $('.cupones_bienvenida_todos');
var tipoCupon ='';

$.each(response.data, function (i) {
  if (response.data[i].Tipo_cupon == 1){
    tipoCupon = "Cupón de 60%";
  }
  else if(response.data[i].Tipo_cupon == 1){
    tipoCupon = "Cupón de 80%";
  }
  else{
    tipoCupon = "Cupón de 100%";
  }

  $('<tr class="cupones"/>')
  .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td')
  .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-radio item-content')
    .text(response.data[i].Cod_Cliente + " - " + response.data[i].Nombre)))
  .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(tipoCupon))
  .append('<div class="cod_cupon" style="display:none">' +
    response.data[i].Identificador + '</div>')
  .append('<div class="tipo_cupon" style="display:none">' +
    response.data[i].Tipo_cupon + '</div>')
  .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td')
  .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-checkbox item-content')
  .append('<input type="checkbox" name="cupon_check" class="cupon_check" value="' +
    response.data[i].Identificador + '"/>')
  .append($('<span/>').addClass('item-media')
    .append('<i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>'))))
  .appendTo(cupones_bienvenida_todos);
  if (cantidad_llaves === 0) {
    $('.cupon_check').prop('disabled', true)
  }
});
llenarVista();
```

Supongamos que de esta tabla me genera 3 registros, ¿como puedo obtener el valor de la clase `tipo_cupon`del ultimo registro que se genero?.
Con esta función vuelvo a llenar la tabla, según un JSON obtenido y a partir de esta función es donde debo obtener el último valor de la tabla generada dinámicamente.

```
function llenarVista(){
  if(json_cupones_welcome){
    json_cupones_welcome_parse = JSON.parse(json_cupones_welcome);
    var identificador_cupon =0;
    var cupones = $('.cupones');
    var tipo_cupon; //60%, 80% y 100%
    $.each(json_cupones_welcome_parse.checkbox, function (index,value) {
      identificador_cupon = value.identificador;
      cupones.find(".cupon_check[value='"+identificador_cupon+"']")
        .prop('checked', true);

      $.each(value.productos_checkbox, function(index,producto){
        productos_seleccionados.push(producto);
        productos_checkbox_seleccionados.push(producto);
      });
      obj_checkbox_seleccionados.productos_checkbox = productos_checkbox_seleccionados;
    });
    //En esta linea es en donde estoy intentando obtener el ultimo valor
    tipo_cupon = cupones.find(".tipo_cupon").text();
    console.log("TIPO CUPON, DEL JSON RETORNADO");
    console.log(tipo_cupon);
    // Este console lo que hace es devolverme  el valor de la clase `tipo_cupon`
    // pero de todos los registros, es decir si tengo 3 registros en la tabla dinamica,
    // en esta linea me imprime 3  veces el `tipo_cupon`

    $.each(productos_seleccionados, function(index, value){
      identificador_cupon = value.codCupon;
      cupones.find(".cupon_check[value='"+identificador_cupon+"']")
        .prop('checked', true);
    });
    productosSeleccionados();
    $(".lista_productos_elegir > li").remove();
    $(".lista_productos_elegir3 > li").remove();
    $(".lista_productos_elegir4 > li").remove();
    cuponesDescuentoProducto1(idPedido);
    cuponesDescuentoProducto3(idPedido);
    cuponesDescuentoProducto4(idPedido);
    $('.tbla-productos1').show();
    $('.tbla-productos3').show();
    $('.tbla-productos4').show();
  }
}
```

De antemano muy agradecido.

Comment: Es posible simplificar mas el ejemplo? o que agregues una estructura html para saber como ordenas exactamente tus elementos? Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Vale, no entiendo muy bien como estas estructurando exactamente tus elementos pero voy a tratar de hacer un ejemplo mínimo a ver si es lo que buscas.

Si quieres saber cual es el valor de una ultima etiqueta x que es hermana de otros elementos solo tienes que utilizar `last()`.

Esto quiere decir que, tienes tus clases `.tipo_cupon`, si lo estructuras de la siguiente manera, encontraras el ultimo hermano de la clase.

Como no se si es hija de un elemento especifico te lo coloco como si fuera solo un elemento hermano:

> Ejemplo:

```
$(".tipo_cupon").last().html();

// O

$(".tipo_cupon").last().text();
```

Si quieres especificar de que elemento padre es solo coloca el elemento padre dentro del query selector:

> Ejemplo

```
$("padre .tipo_cupon").last().html();
// ...
```

Todo esto lo ejecutas luego de generar tu tabla, o con un evento separado.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Hice un pequeño código para que te puedas guiar, la idea es esta: cree un **array** con valores de **nombre** y **apellidos** el cual emulará los datos que vienen en tu **JSON**, ese **array** llenará la tabla inicialmente, luego cree un botón que dice **"Obtener el último"** el cual al presionarlo te dará el valor del último elemento; el último elemento es aquel que tiene la clase `tipo_cupon`, hay dos un `div` y un `input` para que te guíes y veas como puedes obtener el valor ya sea de un `input`, de un `div` o cualquier otro elemento la noción es la misma. Luego cree un botón que dice **"agregar más registros"** el cual te permitirá seguir llenando la tabla emulando el proceso que describes de lo dinámico, una vez vuelvas a llenar la tabla puedes volver a clickear el botón **"Obtener el último"** y el resultado debería de ser diferente y creo que con esto cubriría tu pregunta, espero sea lo que estas buscando:

```js
const array = [{"nombre":"David", "apellido":"Molina"},
               {"nombre":"Freddy", "apellido":"Molina"},
               {"nombre":"Carolina", "apellido":"Coronel"}];

const llenarTabla = (array) => {

  array.forEach((elemento) => {

    $("table")
    .append(`<tr>
               <td>`+elemento.nombre+`</td>
               <td>`+elemento.apellido+`</td>
               <td>
                 <div class="tipo_cupon">`+elemento.nombre+` `+elemento.apellido+`</div>
               </td>
               <td>
                 <input class="tipo_cupon2" value="`+elemento.apellido+` `+elemento.nombre+`">
               </td>
             </tr>`)

  });

} 

llenarTabla(array);

$("#obtener").on("click", function(){
  
  let val1 = $("table tr:last").find(".tipo_cupon").text();
  let val2 = $("table tr:last").find(".tipo_cupon2").val();
  
  alert("El último valor para el div con la clase .tipo_cupon es "+val1+" y para el input es "+val2);
  
});

$("#llenar").on("click", function(){
  
  let array = [{"nombre":"Carlos", "apellido":"Coronel"},
               {"nombre":"Ruth", "apellido":"Ruíz"},
               {"nombre":"Pastora", "apellido":"Marín"}];
  
  llenarTabla(array);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="obtener">Obtener el último</button>
<button id="llenar">agregar más registros</button>
<br><br>
<table border="1">
 <thead>
   <th>Nombre</th>
   <th>Apellido</th>
   <th>Nombre Completo div</th>
   <th>Nombre Completo input</th>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Únicamente agregue lo siguiente:

```
tipo_cupon = cupones.find(".tipo_cupon").last();
console.log(tipo_cupon.text());
```